# Create link in woocommerce login template

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In my site is a custom registration form.
When a new customer is trying to checkout the customer is presented with a page stating that he/she must be logged in to proceed to checkout. They can click on the login link and getting this page:

[image]

When they are new they must register. In the image above is a text stated to proceed to the "Shipping and Billing" section. This is just text. See the code below.

`<?php
    woocommerce_login_form(
        array('message'  => __( 'If you have shopped with us before, please enter your details in the boxes below. If you are a new customer please proceed to the Billing &amp; Shipping section.', 'woocommerce' ),
            'redirect' => wc_get_page_permalink( 'checkout' ),
            'hidden'   => true
        )
    );
?>`

This code is in the form-login.php template file.

I want to change the words "Shipping and Billing" into a link to my User Registration page. Somehow I'm not able to get it to work. Is it because it is in a message in an array? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Kharis Sulistiyono over at WordPress dot org, hereby the answer:

I replaced the code with:

```
<?php

$register_url = get_permalink('4491');

woocommerce_login_form(
array('message'  => __( 'If you have shopped with us before, please enter your details in the boxes below. </br></br><strong>If you are a new customer please <a href="'.esc_url($register_url ).'">register here</a>.</strong>', 'woocommerce' ),
    'redirect' => wc_get_page_permalink( 'checkout' ),
    'hidden'   => true
)
);

?>
```

Where 4491 is the ID number of the post/page.